# How to fix Error code: 221002 on Wii

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-wii

I am trying to do a system transfer from my Wii to Wii U and I have to accept the User Agreements but I can't because I keep getting error code 221002. I've checked the Nintendo support website and it says the code doesn't exist. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is your Wii connected to the internet?

Comment: Yes it is connected.

Comment: according the nintendo site it's because your wii can't connect to the internet.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Nintendo's Support Site](https://www.nintendo.co.uk/Support/Wii/Troubleshooting/Error-Codes/221001-221002-637298.html) your system can not connect to the internet.

> Error Code(s) 221001 - 221002
>
> This error code displays the following message:
> Unable to connect to the Internet.
>
> To try and fix this error, please try the following:
> Please correct the internet settings and perform a connection test.
> If a connection cannot be established even though the connection test is succesful the server is either busy or down. If the server is busy, please try again later. If the server is down, please contact Nintendo.

You need to go through the settings and get them in a proper state so you can get the system online. If it is a wired connection then it may be enough to just accept the auto settings and retest the connection. If its a WIFI connection make sure you have the network name and passowrd (if needed) correct. It should then allow you to continue forward through the process.